# Java: explain : this class is deprecate

Tags: java, deprecated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The constructor Date(…) is deprecated. What does it mean? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999766/the-constructor-date-is-deprecated-what-does-it-mean-java)

When I use `SMSManager` object on `Android`, `Eclipse` notice that `this class is deprecate` and there is a crossline at `SMSManager`, but everything works normally.

Who can explain for me this, please.

thanks :)

Comment: Did you try wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation ?

Comment: This is a Java guide about it - basically deprecation means a function/method/class/whatever is not recommended for use, and something else probably replaced it. It might disappear in a future release: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html

Comment: a simple google search should yield all the information you're looking for - https://www.google.com/search?q=java+deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A deprecated class or method is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists. It is so potentially bad/out-dated, in fact, that you should no longer use it, since it has been superseded and may cease to exist in the future.

Answer (score 3):

[@Deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html)

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists. Compilers warn when a deprecated program element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means it will no longer be supported in the future. See the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html

> This class is deprecated.
>
> Replaced by android.telephony.SmsManager that supports both GSM and CDMA.

Answer (score 0):

> This class is deprecated.
>
> Replaced by android.telephony.SmsManager that supports both GSM and CDMA.

[See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation doesn't mean that the Object isn't working anymore, it means that a new one exists now and that you should be using that new one. In your case, you should use `android.telephony.SMSManager` and not `android.telephony.gsm.SMSManager`.