# Adding seconds to a Date

Tags: java

I need add a certain time in seconds to my Date. For this, I'm making it:

```
Date startTime = dayStart(dateSelected);    
startTime.setSeconds(startTime.getSeconds()+30);
```

But, for this way I get this alerts:

Multiple markers at this line 
- The method setSeconds(int) from the type Date is deprecated
- The method getSeconds() from the type Date is deprecated

What's the better way to don't get these deprecated alerts?

Comment: do you know what deprecated means?

Comment: From [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setSeconds-int-): **Deprecated**. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by `Calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, int seconds)`.

Comment: Why do questions like this get -1 so often?  He is asking what a better way to do this is.  That seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: Unfortunately, some developers like to underestimate others. I know something is not necessarily wrong deprecated. Just wanted to know a more interesting way to do it.

Comment: Well, the -1 is gone now.  ;)

Comment: Perhaps the -1 is because this question has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding n hours to a date in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581258/adding-n-hours-to-a-date-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The constructor Date(...) is deprecated. What does it mean? (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999766/the-constructor-date-is-deprecated-what-does-it-mean-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

> What's the better way to don't get these deprecated alerts?

Do not use that terrible class, `java.util.Date`. Use its replacement, `Instant`.

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant().plusSeconds( 30 )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 that supplanted the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar` and `Date`.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

### Start of day

> Date startTime = dayStart(dateSelected);

If you want the first moment of the day, you need a `LocalDate` (date) and a `ZoneId` (time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now( z ) ;  // Get the current date as seen in a particular time zone.
```

Get the start of that date. Specify a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Always let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day. Some dates in some zones do *not* start at 00:00:00. They might start at another time such as 01:00:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

### Date-time math

You can perform date-time math by calling the `plus…` & `minus…` methods.

Specify a span-of-time not attached to the timeline using either `Duration` or `Period` classes.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( 30 ) ;
```

Add.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plus( d ) ;
```

Or combine those 2 lines into 1.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plusSeconds( 30 ) ;
```

### Converting

If you need to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

The `java.util.Date` legacy class represents a moment in UTC with a resolution of milliseconds. Its replacement is `java.time.Instant`, also a moment in UTC but with a much finer resolution of nanoseconds.

You can extract a `Instant` from a `ZonedDateTime`, effectively adjusting from some time zone to UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdtLater.toInstant() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 13):

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for Date class reads

> As of JDK 1.1, the Calendar class should be used to convert between
>   dates and time fields and the DateFormat class should be used to
>   format and parse date strings. The corresponding methods in Date are
>   deprecated.

And `setSeconds` method in JavaDoc has following warning

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   Calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, int seconds).

That means you should do something like this

```
int numberOfseconds = 30;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dateSelected);
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, numberOfSeconds);
```

Comment: Thanks! His answer was very complete.

Comment: @HelioBentzen you are welcome, I am always glad to help a fellow developer

Answer (score 4):

The methods on `Date` are deprecated for good reason.
All of that functionality has been moved to the `Calendar` class:

```
    Date oldDate = new Date();
    Calendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
    gcal.setTime(oldDate);
    gcal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    Date newDate = gcal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = cal.getTime();

        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        Date later = cal.getTime();

        System.out.println("Now: " + now);
        System.out.println("Later: " + later);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding 30 seconds to the old java.util.Date (not recommended but sometimes useful):

```
Date startTime = dayStart(dateSelected);    
startTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + 30 * 1000);
```

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html), released with Java SE 8 in March 2014.