# Show warning for usage of methods/constructor annotated with custom annotation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, structural-search

I've got an application that uses an ORM solution that requires the default constructor to be left in the class. To prevent my accidental usage of this default constructor, I would like to highlight any usages of it with warning.

I'm currently annotating it with a custom annotation like "@DoNotUse" but I can't figure out how to get Intellij to mark its usages with a warning.

I don't believe structural search inspections can solve this problem.

Is my only hope a plugin now?

**EDIT:** Since someone obviously didn't read the question, I am not looking for a reason why `@Deprecated` is causing a statement in my code to be marked with a warning, I'm looking for a way to replicate this effect with other custom annotations.

Comment: Make the constructor private. Most ORMs use reflection to instantiate classes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to try this now but I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: Why you don't use @Deprecated annotation?

Comment: Actually, yes I was using this in the past but it was sort of confusing so I was hoping if a better solution exists.

Comment: @dehasi that is not a good idea because this classes isn't Deprecated.

Comment: @domfarr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999766/the-constructor-date-is-deprecated-what-does-it-mean-java/1999796#1999796

Comment: @domfarr You can mark only target constructor

Comment: @dehasi this class isn't being phased out. Deprecate means you should not use this class as it will be **deleted** in future releases.

Comment: @VMAtm I'm unsure what your are talking about? Please expand

Comment: He means you can mark a single method/constructor as being deprecated with: `@Deprecated public Test() {}`

Comment: I get that, sorry, I mean in the context of this question. @nulldev are you planning on deleting this class in the future? If not, Deprecate is the wrong annotation.

Comment: No I don't but `@Deprecated` doesn't actually mean a class will be phased out. It only means the class should not be used (Read the official Javadocs for it). **But I still prefer if I can get a custom annotation to do this!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is possible using Structural Search. However it requires knowledge of the internals of IntelliJ IDEA, so it's hard to figure out.

Use the following pattern:

```
new $Constructor$();
```

Click `Edit Variables...` and set the `Script Text` of `Constructor` to:

```
import com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil
def method = __context__.parent.resolveMethod()
AnnotationUtil.findAnnotation(method, "fully.qualified.annotation.DoNotUse") != null
```

This should find all invocations of default constructors where the constructor is annotated with `fully.qualified.annotation.DoNotUse`. After you get it working, create a Structural Search inspection with the pattern.

Comment: **WOAH,** this actually works! Accepting this right away! Thanks so much!

Comment: I can't get your example to work in Android Studio 2.3. I'd like to do something similar but allow the annotation to be used on methods, fields or constructors. Additionally I'm trying to allow a message to be specified and shown in the error (not a must have)

So are you saying the `new $Constructor$();` part needs to be in the **Search Template** textbox when you add a new Search Template under structural search? Also, what do you mean by "**After you get it working**, create a Structural Search inspection with the pattern." Isn't that what the `new $Constructor$();` is? Thanks

Comment: @JoshuaKing: He means you should take that search configuration and use it in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-custom-inspections.html