# Android: Why is the constructor for SoundPool deprecated?

Tags: java, android, audio, constructor, deprecated

Does it mean that we cannot use it anymore?
 What should we use if the min API is set below 21?
Also, is it okay to ignore the warning as older applications built using it work on the new OSes?

Comment: Questions about "why did Developer X do Thing Y?" are unsuitable for Stack Overflow. Usually, the only party who can provide a clear answer is Developer X, and Developer X is unlikely to see your question. Anyone else can only offer opinions. "Does it mean that we cannot use it anymore?" -- you are welcome to use it, but you should use `SoundPool.Builder` for projects with a `minSdkVersion` of 21 or higher. "What should we use if the min API is set below 21?" -- the `SoundPool` constructor, as you have no choice.

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean that there would be no issues if I continue using the constructor? Also couldn't I just use MediaPlayer and notice no issues for short sounds?

Comment: "So does it mean that there would be no issues if I continue using the constructor?" -- for the time being, yes. "Also couldn't I just use MediaPlayer and notice no issues for short sounds?" -- `SoundPool` offers features that differ from `MediaPlayer` (e.g., prioritized streams). I would not avoid `SoundPool` merely because its constructor is deprecated. Whether `SoundPool` meets your needs overall, I cannot say.

Comment: Thank you, I just used them both in an app to know about it. I also provided an answer about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527134/audiotrack-soundpool-or-mediaplayer-which-should-i-use/39184503#39184503

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deprecated meaning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111774/deprecated-meaning)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Why the SoundPool constructor was deprecated

The old [`SoundPool` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#SoundPool(int,%20int,%20int)) was deprecated in favor of using [`SoundPool.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.Builder.html) to build the `SoundPool` object. The [old constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#SoundPool(int,%20int,%20int)) had three parameters: `maxStreams`, `streamType`, and `srcQuality`.

- The `maxStreams` parameter can still be [set with the Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.Builder.html#setMaxStreams(int)). (And if you don't set it, it defaults to 1.)
- The `streamType` parameter is replaced by [`AudioAttributes`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.html), which is more descriptive than `streamType`. (See the different stream type constants starting [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_ALARM).) With `AudioAttributes` you can specify the *usage* (why you are playing the sound), the *content type* (what you are playing), and *flags* (how to play it).
- The `srcQuality` parameter was supposedly there to set the sample-rate converter quality. However, it was never implemented and setting it had no effect.

Thus, `SoundPool.Builder` is better than the old constructor because `maxStreams` does not need to be explicitly set, `AudioAttributes` contains more information than `streamType`, and the useless `srcQuality` parameter was eliminated. That is why the old constructor was deprecated.

### Using the deprecated constructor to support versions before API 21

You may still use the old constructor and ignore the warnings if you like. "Deprecated" means that it still works but is no longer the recommended way of doing things.

If you wish to make use of the new constructor while still supporting old versions you can use an `if` statement to select the API version.

```
SoundPool mSoundPool;
int mSoundId;

//...

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     mSoundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
            .setMaxStreams(10)
            .build();
} else {
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
}

mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.somesound, 1);

// ...

mSoundPool.play(mSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mMiB_zW1HY) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so if this other way of building an object is more descriptive, why not add this as another constructor, as java allows multiple constructers, why did they specifically have to take steps to say that this method is bad to use anymore?

Comment: @Harsha, Using a `Builder` is not just adding a new constructor. It is a new class that is used to build (or construct) a `SoundPool`. This design pattern seems to be a trend. (See [`StaticLayout.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.Builder.html), for example.) But even if they were just adding a new constructor, it is fairly common to deprecate old constructors that are not recommended any more (see Java [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#constructor_summary)).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`SoundPool.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.Builder.html) instead. The way a SoundPool is created has been changed. You are encouraged to use the new way.

Comment: I looked at it, but I also need to know why it has been deprecated and what happens if it is still used.

Comment: Please, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999766/the-constructor-date-is-deprecated-what-does-it-mean-java