# Selenium WebDriverWait is not being imported correctly

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

Im trying to use WebDriverWait but when I use it, it has a line through.

[image]

the import being called is

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Comment: That is because the constructor you are using is deprecated, which your IDE would probably tell you if you hovered your mouse over that line, or you could also read on if you would have just looked at the official documentation of the tool you are using. It has absolutly nothing to do with "not importing correctly" and isn't even an error in any way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java's Date(...) constructor is deprecated; what does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999766/javas-date-constructor-is-deprecated-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS thanks for your comment, I forgot to get back to you, your solution is correct and so is the link to the similar question, I just fixed mine by using an older version of selenium, it wouldn't work because i was using an alpha version. I thought it was safer going to an older beta instead of changing source code

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work because I was using the newest alpha version when its not stable

I had to download and add the last stable Jar [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)